# I Cant save the data from my form in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a issue after to enter the information on my form,  I dont get any error, but when check the console of server  appear this:

> Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2017-06-22 18:33:54 -0600 Processing
>   by UsersController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"9X/XZ0KJ+GqMaoJZTDlFq8WsHtfMUssqJ/DEr0JYCOSnv+hAoMPOW+GVOv8J5MBLp9DBAcmKeR6K2S5UhsX0lQ==",
>   "user"=>{"usuario"=>"Hschwartz", "nombres"=>"Herbert Mauricio",
>   "apellidos"=>"Schwartz Melara",
>   "correo"=>"mauricio_schwartzm@hotmail.com",
>   "nivel_autoridad"=>"Administrador", "password_digest"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Crear mi cuenta"}
>   Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :authenticity_token, :user, :commit
>   **(0.0ms)  begin transaction    (0.0ms)  rollback transaction**   Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application   Rendered
>   users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.5ms) Completed 200 OK
>   in 254ms (Views: 242.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

If you see application do a recall automatically, I dont not why.

That's is the information from the controller file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Usuario registrado exitosamente"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash[:fail] = "Error al registrar usuario"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(:user)
  end
end
```

I will apreciate if you have some suggest to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:usuario, :nombres, ...) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to list each field and still want to use permit all (Allthough it's not recommended for security reason) you can use

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit!
  end
```